# Can ionic2's pages support nested directory structure?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I see the `pages` directory of many Ionic 2 projects is a flatted structure like below (if we use its generation command, the generated directory structure is flatted).

e.g.

```
    pages/
      |- login/
      |    |-login.html
      |    |-login.scss
      |    |_login.ts
      |- logout/
      |    |-logout.html
      |    |-logout.scss
      |    |_logout.ts
      |- order-list/
      |    |-order-list.html
      |    |-order-list.scss
      |    |_order-list.ts
      |- order-detail/
      |    |-order-detail.html
      |    |-order-detail.scss
      |    |_order-detail.ts
```

But if a project includes many pages, i hope the `pages` directory supports sub directories like below:

e.g.

```
    pages/
      |- auth/
      |     |- login/
      |     |    |-login.html
      |     |    |-login.scss
      |     |    |_login.ts
      |     |- logout/
      |     |    |-logout.html
      |     |    |-logout.scss
      |     |    |_logout.ts
      |- order/
      |     |- list/
      |     |    |-list.html
      |     |    |-list.scss
      |     |    |_list.ts
      |     |- detail/
      |     |    |-detail.html
      |     |    |-detail.scss
      |     |    |_detail.ts
```

Does Ionic 2's `pages` support this? The same question to others directory like `providers` and `pipes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it does. In fact, instead of grouping things in terms of *what they are* (pages, providers, pipes, directives, and so on) I do prefer to group them in terms of *what they do* just like [Angular 2 style guides](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-07) recommends.

> **Folders-by-Feature Structure STYLE 04-07**
>
> Do create folders named for the feature area they represent.
>
> Why? A developer can locate the code, identify what each file
>   represents at a glance, the structure is as flat as it can be, and
>   there is no repetitive nor redundant names.
>
> Why? The LIFT guidelines are all covered.
>
> Why? Helps reduce the app from becoming cluttered through organizing
>   the content and keeping them aligned with the LIFT guidelines.
>
> Why? When there are a lot of files (e.g. 10+), locating them is easier
>   with a consistent folder structure and more difficult in a flat
>   structure.

Just keep in mind that you'll have to update the references both in all the files and also in the components `templateUrl` property (if you're **not** using the RC version). So

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html',
  pipes: [ ... ],
  directives: [ ... ]
})
...
```

will turn into:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/auth/login/login.html',
  pipes: [ ... ],
  directives: [ ... ]
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does.

You just have to respect the nesting when importing the pages for your NgModule in src/app/app.module.ts