# ionic-cli to generate pages in certain folders

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I am using `ionic-cli 2` for generating pages for my `ionic` project. I would like keep my pages separately in  different folders . For example , I would like to keep pages like `Login` , `Signup` in a separate folder called `authentication` . But at the same time I would like to enjoy the `ionic generate page` command to quickly setup the page inside the `authentication` folder. Currently `ionic-cli` would generate the pages in `pages` folder. How can I make it in `pages/authentication` folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but this worked for me using the @latest ionic (3.12.0)

Generate "sub-pages" from the app's root folder as you would generate "top-level" pages. Then, drag them to their intended place using Visual Studio Code.

Obviously you want to rename stuff such as modules and classes. For example, for the 'home' and 'standings' sub-pages of the 'team' page, I renamed the classes from `HomePage` and `StandingsPage` to `TeamHomePage` and `TeamStandingsPage` respectively.

Alternatively (and in retrospect recommended), name the pages using the desired structure, e.g., `ionic generate page team-home` (you'll still have to move them manually). This is especially useful for repeating patterns, e.g., if you also want 'home' and 'standings' sub-pages for say a 'tournaments' page.

Also see [Can ionic2's pages support nested directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025738/can-ionic2s-pages-support-nested-directory-structure).

Answer (score 2):

Just run

```
ionic generate page pages/authentication
```

more information https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate

Comment: This does not address the question.
The command will generate page named "pages-authentication" under folder "pages". The question ask how to generate pages under pages/authentication.

Comment: this exactly addresses the question. COMMANDS  for the @raj would be .....`ionic generate page authentication/login ` AND `ionic generate page authentication/Signup`

Answer (score 1):

`ionic g page src/app/pages/{your_pageName}`
This Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate
Seems that you can specify the folder where you want to generate your page or component directly when you call the command.

Typing `ionic g page my_dir/my_page` generate a page component into the my_dir directory.

Comment: erroneous assumption as this  in later versions will generate a page and folder named my_dir-my_page

Answer (score 0):

I know this gets tricky in the beginning. Here, I'm mentioning the steps to create a page under specific directory.

Suppose your project follows the structure of directory as:

- src

  - app

    - components

      - pages
      - pipes

To create a page under "pages", navigate to "app" directory and use command:
**ionic g page pages/test**

Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate

Answer (score 0):

before creating a separate folder you have to manually create an authentication folder into your app folder.

CLI > ionic generate page authentication/login